# How to test partials in views specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to have a user menu in my layouts/application.html.erb. In future, I plan to move it to a partial layouts/_user_menu.html.erb.

How should I start, write tests for this menu just in application.html.erb_spec.rb, and then as refactoring to move it to partial, leaving all tests in application.html.erb_spec.rb?

Or write its separate test _user_menu.html.erb_spec.rb? In this case, how can I test application.html.erb to render this partial? I don't thinks its good idea to use html selectors here, and think about something like in my application.html.erb_spec.rb:

```
expect(view).to render_partial 'user_menu'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
response.should render_template(:partial => 'partial_name')
```

Comment: I does not work as expected. It looks for such partial as 'application/_partial_name', and not 'layouts/_partial_name'. If I explicitly check for render_template(partial: 'layouts/_partial_name') it works. But it is a little confusing, why cant I check render_template(partial: 'layouts/partial_name') instead of render_template(partial: 'layouts/_partial_name')

Comment: I also tried what you want but I i found above method so we have to write real name of file because we are trying to check 'render_templete', thats why we have write the partial name with '_'.